# Python3 how to raise a ValueError for a date time object if its not in the right format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

For a uni project we have to create a program conforming to some tests that we have been given. The tests use magic numbers as inputs for the functions. I know how to get it to return a datetime object. Just dont know how to raise the error!

my code:

```py
    import datetime
    def time_to_datetime(datetimeSTR):
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeSTR, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
        if datetimeSTR != datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeSTR, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'):
            raise ValueError('The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM')
        else:
            return datetime_obj
```

Test Code:

```py
    import datetime
    import os
    import unittest   # Standard unittest framework.

    import utils   # The module implementing JourneyOptions class.


    class TestTimeToDatetime(unittest.TestCase):
        """Tests for the time_to_datetime function."""

        def test_invalid_time_is_rejected(self):
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
                utils.time_to_datetime('2019/06/09 12:60')
            self.assertEqual(
                'The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM',
                str(cm.exception))

        def test_valid_time_yields_a_dattime_object(self):
            d = utils.time_to_datetime('2019/06/09 12:59')
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(d, datetime.datetime))
```

these are the results i get:

```
======================================================================

ERROR: test_valid_time_yields_a_dattime_object (__main__.TestTimeToDatetime)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/s5115426/Desktop/tests/test_utils.py", line 21, in test_valid_time_yields_a_dattime_object
    d = utils.time_to_datetime('2019/06/09 12:59')
  File "C:\Users\s5115426\Desktop\tests\utils.py", line 25, in time_to_datetime
    raise ValueError('The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM')
ValueError: The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

======================================================================
FAIL: test_invalid_time_is_rejected (__main__.TestTimeToDatetime)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/s5115426/Desktop/tests/test_utils.py", line 18, in test_invalid_time_is_rejected
    str(cm.exception))
AssertionError: 'The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM' != 'unconverted data remains: 0'
- The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
+ unconverted data remains: 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume `if datetimeSTR != datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeSTR, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'):` is always True, since `datetime.datetime.strptime` returns a datetime, not a string.

Comment: `datetime.strptime()` is raising a `ValueError` Due to the invalid input before you do. This is why your test checking the error message is failing, because it’s  returning a different error message to the one you are expecting. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you are making is that strptime raises a value error if the date string does not match the given format.  for example:

```
date_str = '2019/06/09 12:60'
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
.
.
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

datetime_obj never gets set because strptime never returns a value.

Also, as noted, you are comparing the response from strptime to the inout string -- that will never work.

Try a simpler approach:

```
import datetime
def time_to_datetime(datetimeSTR):
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeSTR, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    return datetime_obj
```

Or you can catch any exception and reraise (imo, bad practice, but might be worth doing to illustrate.

```
import datetime
def time_to_datetime(datetimeSTR):
    try:
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimeSTR, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    except ValueErr as err:
        print(err)
        raise ValueError('The time must have the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM')
    else:
        return datetime_obj
```

This way, you see how strptime behaves for various inputs in your test and you have error handling in your function .... though, as I indicated, reraising an error is (imo) bad practice.

Comment: so if i were to try and catch the error the correct way how would i go about this?

Comment: @Flirps you can allow the exception to be raised by strptime and note that it is still a value error -- try it on the python command line and you'll see for yourself.    OTOH, you can catch the error and reraise it with your own message ... both are valid approaches.  Personally I feel live the former is better real world practice.  An assertion in a context manager that checks for an exception will work either way -- but the message will be different.